# Google Cloud SQL instance upscale and downscale with Zero downtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an application using the Google Cloud PostgreSQL service. Higher availability is already enabled on the instance . Now I want to upscale/downscale the number of core and RAM of instance with zero downtime.Is there any approach to achieve zero downtime.Also there is read replica create with the instance. In case of up scaling I have to upscale the replica first and then the main instance. Second in case of down scaling I just down grade the main instance as replica can not be downscale.

Comment: I dont think vertical scaling is supported in Cloud SQL managed service. You can configure the auto increase of the disk size but not the RAM/CPU

Comment: You will have downtime. You cannot vertically scale Cloud SQL instances with Read Replicas.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to edit instances with zero downtime, the best way to handle that would be being prepared to have downtime, that can also happen during maintenance windows.

Regarding upscaling/downscaling, you can do that with the number of cores and its memory, both for master and read replicas, what you cannot downscale is the SSD Storage size